# Create circle with Google+ Domain API 404 Not Found

Tags: api, dns, google-plus

I am trying to create a Circle in user’s Google+ account. I followed the Quick start (https://developers.google.com/+/domains/quickstart/java) to configure Service Account and its credentials and delegate domain-wide authority to the Service account. When I run the code I get the 404 Not found response.

Here is my code:

```
package com.google.plus.samples.quickstart.domains;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.PlusDomains;
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.Acl;
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.Activity;
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.PlusDomainsAclentryResource;
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.Circle;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.Person;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class DomainDelegation {
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "serviceaccountemail@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH =
  "privatekeypath.p12";
private static final String USER_EMAIL = "user1@mygoogledomain.com";
private static final List<String> SCOPE = Arrays.asList(
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");

private static PlusDomains authenticate() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

System.out.println(String.format("Authenticate the domain for %s", USER_EMAIL));

HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPE)
    .setServiceAccountUser(USER_EMAIL)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
        new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
    .build();

// Create and return the Plus service object
PlusDomains service = new PlusDomains.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
    .setApplicationName("Test")
    .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
return service;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
// Create an authorized API client
PlusDomains service = authenticate();

Circle circle = new Circle();
circle.setDisplayName("Tech support");
Circle result = service.circles().insert("me", circle).execute();

System.out.println("Created 'Tech support' circle with id: " + result.getId());
  }
}
```

Here is the response I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
Not Found
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1045)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
        at com.google.plus.samples.quickstart.domains.DomainDelegation.main(DomainDelegation.java:130)
```

How can I fix the error or figure out which page it cannot find?

Comment: Can you confirm whether that account already has a circle called "Tech support"?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing the default URL using this code:

```
PlusDomains service = new PlusDomains.Builder(httpTransport,
                jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("Test")
                .setRootUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/")
                .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
```